# Branch.io links don't always get picked up as a universal link

Tags: branch.io

Using the same branch link I seem to find different behaviour for whether the link is recognised as an iOS Universal.

My devices are all iOS 9.3. Yet on some I follow the branch link to install the app and then tapping on the link opens the app as expected.

On other devices the same link will install the app, but when tapping on it subsequently it is not recognised as a universal link and so ends up going to the store again.

I can't seem to find any consistency as to why this happens.

Any suggestions how to diagnose the cause of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alex from Branch.io here:

This is strange, and not something we have heard in the past. It's possible Universal Links on some of these devices have been inadvertently disabled (which is annoyingly easy to do) or you are testing from an app where Universal Links are not supported.

If you paste an example link into Notes on a device where things *aren't* working, and then long-press on it, do you see an `Open in [App]` option?

You can also check out our [Universal Links troubleshooting guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links)

Comment: It is odd. Today it is working on the device that failed previously - without anything being changed.  I am not sure what is happening so will try to re-produce it consistently.

Comment: How strange! If you do manage to get it to reproduce consistently, I would be very interested to hear more.